# How to make my other functions work

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Here is the code. I created a table called `players` and added the sprite in function `addbalo`. When I took the sprite out of the `scene:createScene`. Every other function using it doesn't work anymore. For instance the sprite player used to be part of `ScreenGroup:insert(player)` but when I moved it to a function so the timer would work, everything else using it doesn't work any more.

Function `sprite` no longer works

```
local storyboard = require( "storyboard" )
local scene = storyboard.newScene()

local mydata = require( "mydata" )

local physics = require("physics")
physics.start()


players = {} 


local function start(event)
    if event.phase == "began" then
      addbaloTimer = timer.performWithDelay(1000, addbalo, -1)

     end
   end
 local function addbalo()
p_options = 
  {
    -- Required params
    width = 237,
    height = 252,
    numFrames = 7,
    -- content scaling
    sheetContentWidth = 1660,
    sheetContentHeight = 252,

    }


  height = math.random(display.contentCenterX - 240, display.contentCenterY + 240)
  playerSheet = graphics.newImageSheet( "balloon.png", p_options )
    player = display.newSprite( playerSheet, { name="player", loopCount=1 , start=1, count=7, time=500, loopDirection = "forward"} )
    player.anchorX = 0.5
    player.anchorY = 0.5
    player.x = height
    player.y = display.contentCenterY + 500
    player.speed = 4
    physics.addBody(player, "dynamic", {density=3, bounce=0, friction=0.5})
    player.gravityScale = -1
    players:insert(player)

end

local function collide(event)
  if event.phase == "began" then
      storyboard.gotoScene("play", "fade", 100)
     end

end

local function sprite(event)
   if event.phase == "began" then 
      players:play()
      end

end

physics.setGravity(0, 9.8)


function scene:createScene( event )
         local screenGroup = self.view

        background = display.newImageRect("bg.png", 900, 1425)
        background.anchorX = 0.5
            background.anchorY = 1
        background.x = display.contentCenterX
        background.y = display.contentHeight
        screenGroup:insert(background)

        bar = display.newImageRect("white.png", 900, 50)
        bar.anchorX = 0.5
        bar.anchorY = 1
        bar.x = display.contentCenterX
        bar.y = display.contentHeight - 1400
        screenGroup:insert(bar)
        physics.addBody(bar, "static", { friction=0.5, bounce=0})





end


function scene:enterScene( event )
       background:addEventListener("touch", start)
        bar:addEventListener( "collision", collide )
      players:addEventListener("touch", sprite)


end



function scene:exitScene( event )
    background:removeEventListener("touch", start)
    bar:removeEventListener( "collision", collide )
    players:removeEventListener("touch", sprite)

end



function scene:destroyScene( event )

end



scene:addEventListener( "createScene", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "enterScene", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "exitScene", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "destroyScene", scene )




return scene
```

Comment: I don't see you adding any methods to `players`.

Comment: This page will introduce you to how methods work: http://www.lua.org/pil/16.html

Comment: Ok... that was helpful but is there a way I can do it without using a table or which method should I use

Comment: The `players` methods that you call aren't even defined in the code you posted. I guess you could define them as stand-alone functions, but I don't know enough about your code to know which is better.